# Unable to update Ubuntu because of no space in /boot

Tags: boot, disk-usage

When trying to update my system, I get the message that I need another 20,1M in /boot.

For the last few years I've often run out of space in /boot and have had to do the usual autoremove of old kernels recommended here. I also did the recommended COMPRESS=xz i /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf. But now I cannot find anything else to remove:

```
bjorn@bjorn-900X3C-900X3D-900X4C-900X4D:~$ ls /boot
config-5.15.0-39-generic      lost+found                System.map-5.15.0-39-generic
efi                           memtest86+.bin            vmlinuz-5.15.0-39-generic
grub                          memtest86+.elf
initrd.img-5.15.0-39-generic  memtest86+_multiboot.bin
```

This leads me to believe that the partitioning when first setting up the system wasn't very clever:

```
bjorn@bjorn-900X3C-900X3D-900X4C-900X4D:~$ df
Filsystem                    1K-block    Använt Tillgängligt Anv% Monterat på
tmpfs                          775588      2156       773432   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root 237386424 210035448     15269416  94% /
tmpfs                         3877920         0      3877920   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            5120         4         5116   1% /run/lock
/dev/sda2                      241965     93595       135878  41% /boot
/dev/sda1                      497696      9144       488552   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs                          775584      2488       773096   1% /run/user/1000
```

To complicate matters, something is broken so that I cannot boot from a USB and run gparted to increase the partition.

Is there anything I could do to eventually be able to normally run updates?

Comment: Thanks for the swift response!Sure, I have those types of files to remove, but I figured they are not stored in /boot ? I don't find that it lets me update anything when I remove from other folders. Would the /var/log count towards the space in /boot?

Comment: No it wouldn't affect boot because you unfortunately gave it its own partition. It looks like when you installed the system, you decided to give boot its own partition of only ~135 MB. That seems like an unfortunate case of bad planning, since this really isn't enough room. And the fact that you gave it its own partition means that this size is rigid and inflexible. You will need to expand the partition which may not be practical depending on the layout of your drives. Alternatively, reinstall the OS and don't make a separate boot partition. Or give it at least 500MB.

Comment: And your / Filesystem is also full 94%.